# What is the site's position on name calling with a somewhat mildly offensive word?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags, offensive

Recently I stumbled upon this comment:

> to the nincompoop who downvoted this question have the decency to explain why you're downvoting the question

The dictionary defines *nincompoop* as:

> - n. A silly, foolish, or stupid person.
> - n. A fool; a blockhead; a simpleton.
> - n. A fool; a silly or stupid person.

Although my Unfriendly/Unkind flag did eventually lead to the comment's deletion, it was marked as *declined*. This suggests that I should not have used this kind of flag, which in turn means that there should be no repercussions for calling someone a *nincompoop*.

Was this just a mistake from the moderators, or are we accepting the employment of this word or other "cocky" words of similar nature?

Comment: I guess that the mod may have thought it's not a personal attack because it's not personally directed to any user, thanks to the anonymity veil that votes have. I agree with your flag, and think it shouldn't have been declined.

Comment: I wasn't involved in this flag, and I probably wouldn't have declined it... but... at least where I'm from, nincompoop is mainly used in a faux-offensive way, much like 'dumb dumb' or 'silly billy'; a tongue-in-cheek remark. That may have played into the decision here; but I can't say for certain the meaning is the same for the moderator or for other users.

Comment: If it is deemed not unwelcome, I guess it's fine then to use it in comments to new users..?

Comment: Whether or not you consider "nincompoop" unfriendly, the implication that a person is _without decency_ most definitely is. Assuming this comment came from the OP of the question, they are not a new contributor and should know better.

Comment: Yeh we're not allowed to call each other names. And any comments asking for why there's a downvote or worse making demands on a downvoter are summarily deleted.

Comment: @Rob yeh nincompoop where we live is something that would make people laugh. It's almost an affectionate way to tease someone. But within the context of the site it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 44):

It doesn't matter what the site's position is.

The [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) is clear:

> No name-calling or personal attacks.

And the code of conduct applies to all sites in the SE network, there is no opt-out.

There is no nor should there be a list of "allowed" or "mildly" name-calling phrases. Allowing for some wiggle room (*non-insults*) will only be abused by both senders and receivers of those "mildly" name-calling phrases.

That flag should haven been marked helpful. We expect that moderators enforce the code of conduct. That the comment is now deleted is a positive outcome already.

Comment: The comment in the OP reads to me like a mere hair's breadth above "downvoting this would just be silly" which I don't know if I can file that under a CoC violation. Inadvisable, perhaps.

Comment: @Magisch really? *to the nincompoop who downvoted this question* ... are you really suggesting that it isn't name-calling if I replace *noncompoop* with *moron*?

Comment: nincompoop is a non-insult in my opinion, it would be like saying "to the silly person who downvoted this question" yeah, thats technically namecalling, and as I said I'd advise against doing it, but come on. Comment should probably be deleted anyways as should other comments asking for downvote explainations without any more specificity, but I wouldn't tar that as a CoC violation.

Comment: @Magisch I wish you luck moderating the non-insults ....

Comment: With the added *"at least have the decency to"* bit I think it's a bit nincompooply to assume it was done in good humour.

Comment: eh. At least where I'm from, that term and others like it are 50/50 on being an actual mild insult vs a weird form of endearment, like saying "no silly" to someone you actually like. I don't know. Context seems to suggest negatively but still

Comment: If it's acceptable in this case, I will immediately start using it in comments to new users who post obviously bad code.

Comment: @Magisch Yes, context is key. Telling "no silly" to your significant other might be fine. Try saying _"the silly person who spun three additional intances yesterday please have the decency to explain why they did so"_ in a work meeting, for example. SO communication is supposed to resemble more the latter than the former, most of the time.

Comment: And good luck if you say the above at the said meeting, and the silly person ends up being above you in the food-chain. A good litmus test about "acceptable" for this kind of thing, IMO, is imagining saying the line to a boss. It doesn't work? Then it might be better to rethink it.

Comment: In a work meeting, you know your audience so can know if a joke will be received well. On SO, you better refrain from any potentially offensive jokes imo, since you don't know who will be on the receiving end. If something requires context to not be offensive, I think unfriendly/unkind flags on it should be marked helpful

Comment: @MartinJames I carefully wrote this sentence *Allowing for some wiggle room (non-insults) will only be abused* with you in mind ;)

Comment: Calling someone a nincompoop where I live would result in laughter - it's not an insult to be taken seriously, however, on stack overflow with the word "downvote" it doesn't conform with our Code of Conduct. Perhaps not a suspendable offence, something that will definitely be deleted immediately.

Answer (score 21):

Oh that was a misclick on my part! I misclicked a few unfriendly flags in the wrong directions on both sides, sorry.

I declined and deleted it at the same time. I use a script that enables me to do this. I made a mistake sorry.

[image]

As for consequences, a person is not going to be censured for one comment like that, it would need to be a pattern or a one off abusive comment. This comment goes against the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), but it's not in the order of terrible comments. If the author continues, it will be a problem.

Comment: A script that enables you to decline and delete the comment anyway? I guess because you say the comment is not unfriendly, but still doesn't need to be kept? So the flagger just used the wrong flag type, but then I wonder, why use different flag types anyway, then the end result is the same: the comment has been deleted?

Comment: @Tom many comments are no longer needed or not useful, in this case the comment should have been deleted. I was handling a stream of comments and misclicked more than one of them. Not the best, I agree.

Comment: I'm not actually talking about your missclick, that happens. What I mean is: why do we need different flag types for comments, then we can end up with declined flags, but deleted comments. Would the to options: "Delete this comment" and "Something else." (or another description for this "custom" option) be enough? You mods can then still delete the comment when it is not needed or trigger another action if it was unfriendly. But I guess this has been discussed in a meta feature-request already :D.

Comment: @Tom fwiw people don't get flag banned for declined comment flags, so they don't carry as much weight. But helpful unfriendly or rude flags go towards an automatic flag against a user to investigate their account. So if a comment is on the line, I am inclined to decline, but still delete. Most comments on the site serve no real purpose after a while, so deletion is not an issue really. The content should be in the posts (this is for main). So a no longer needed flag is usually the safest or a mod flag if in doubt and wanting to explain. An unfriendly flag doesn't do any harm. Make sense?