# Flag about possibly ToS-violating username declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive, display-names

The user:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/12316619

[image]

(clipped for posterity in case something comes of this question).

My comment in the mod flag I raised:

> this user's name could be considered offensive by some

The response:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Yet according to an answer by a moderator:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251684/70345

> ... a username is visible everywhere the user posts. As such it is subject to the terms of service, which require that subscriber-provided content is not offensive.

I'd like to make it clear that I personally have no problem with this username (it is at worst juvenile IMO) but I'm pretty certain that it violates the ToS as described above.

Comment: I agree with the mod. I don't find evidence to support that "peepeepoopoo" is offensive either.

Comment: Which ToS say that a username as "peepeepoopoo" would be disallowed? Could you quote the relevant parts? You haven't done so in your question.

Comment: You think it's "at worst juvenile" yet are surprised that a mod doesn't consider it to be offensive?

Comment: "by some" - please point me to a group containing said people, who are also old enough to be allowed to use the site.

Comment: @yivi I linked to an answer written by a moderator. You should be asking that moderator that question, not me.

Comment: No, you are the one saying the username violates the terms of service. If that's your contention, you should back up your claim. The quote from that answer does nothing of the sort.

Comment: Pee Pee Poo Poo is not offensive. It seems to be a meme. It is not mandatory to understand every meme. That you know two people who get seriously offended when seeing a meme is not a violation of the ToS, the CoC or the consensus on meta what is appropriate.

Comment: *If* the name was made of profanities, you might have a point here, however, I will admit that if someone finds "peepeepoopo" offensive, then I would likely suggest that the internet is not the best place for them to be; as it won't take long to find other words used to describe urine and faeces that is used by those older than a 5 year old.

Comment: The Answer suggests you can leave a comment on one of their posts. Perhaps "beebeebooboo" is less juvenile.. ?

Comment: @Scratte That sounds like the kind of interjection a child would employ when they get stung by a bee.

Comment: I am offended by ketchup, yet people still put it on burgers and fries. Some put it on eggs. I'm sure some real weird-os put it on ketchup.

Comment: Many people tell me that black licorice is offensive and disgusting but I think it's awesome.

Comment: @RobertColumbia A man of culture. But I am also a little affronted that a discussion about a username "peepeepoopoo" went to the topic of licorice.

Comment: Might be inaccurate representation of chick sounds?

Answer (score 17):

There was likely a misunderstanding about what makes something offensive for this website.

The presence of a code of conduct and the drive for making the platform more welcoming to all users does not mean that *everything* that might seem inappropriate is offensive.

In case of doubt, just read the code of conduct. The following points should help you make a better assessment to whether a display name or a comment should be flagged.

> - **No name-calling or personal attacks.**
> - **No bigotry.** We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people [...] don't use language that might offend or alienate.
> - **No harassment.** This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

The display name "peepeepoopoo" is indeed juvenile, but so long as that user is not *calling someone else* a "peepeepoopoo", that, in itself, is not offensive, not unfriendly, not bigotry, not harassment, not abusive, and not something that can significantly disrupt discussion. As such, it is not a violation of the site's policies, and there was no need to flag it.

At best, you can leave a comment in one of their posts suggesting to tweak the display name to something a bit more professional, but even that comment could be deleted after a while.

---

And for completion, the Stack Overflow Terms of Service do not expand on this subject more than the code of conduct already does. The relevant piece is in section 5, User Obligations (emphasis mine):

> Stack Overflow is a community and we expect you to treat each member of the Stack Overflow community with respect. Whether a community member is asking their first question, or is a reputation superstar, we respect you and welcome you, but we also require you to be kind to one another. To prevent bad actors from creating a negative community experience, **we have outlined what we believe to be common sense rules for community participation and reserve the right to pause or terminate your account if you engage in disruptive, abusive, or nefarious behavior** outside of Stack Overflow’s [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), which is hereby incorporated into these Public Network Terms.

To be frank, I do find it a bit odd that it does not mention the code of conduct (maybe this was written before the CoC replaced the Be Nice policy?), but even so, reasonable common sense rules would not pose this display name as offensive. The [Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) outlines uses of a different nature (illegal content, spam, harmful content, sexual content, hate Content, defamation, etc.), also not applicable here.

---

See also:

- [What is the site's position on name calling with a somewhat mildly offensive word?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389413/what-is-the-sites-position-on-name-calling-with-a-somewhat-mildly-offensive-wor)

Comment: one could argue it is self-name-calling and thus must be purged :) can we really trust users with knowing what's offensive to them?

Comment: @OlegValter I don't know of any culture where self name calling in itself is offensive to other people. In fact, when people leave comments of the sort "Oh, that was it, I'm such an idiot!", these are best flagged as no longer needed rather than anything else (U/U or Abusive). And while I would agree that some cases may sit in a borderline, this one IMO does not.

Comment: please reread the above noting that it was an ironic remark...

Comment: @OlegValter That's a ricochet, I like to reply to everything seriously! :)

Comment: ouch, that ricochet hurt :)

Answer (score -8):

The code of conduct section quoted by E_net4 provides good guidance. Let's break it down a little more:

**No name-calling or personal attacks.** The username above isn't a personal attack or insult. The following might count as violations:

- [Famous Stack Overflow user] is a piece of poopoo.
- I want to peepee on [celebrity].
- Poopoo-head [celebrity]

**No bigotry.** The username above isn't bigotry. Here are some possible examples of bigotry:

- [Followers of a certain religion] should eat my poopoo.
- [Political party] supporters like to peepee.

**No harassment.** The username above isn't harassment as it isn't targeted at a specific victim or group of victims. The following might qualify:

- I poopoo on downvoters.
- Drink my peepee.
- Moderators eat my peepeepoopoo.

Comment: *"I want to peepee on [celebrity]."* is a very poor choice for name-calling or personal attacks