# Flagged a comment telling someone to "learn social skills" as unkind, but was declined

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, unfriendly-or-unkind

I recently flagged a comment as "unfriendly or unkind". The comment said something like:

> "if you are going to correct someone's posts, you should first [learn social skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)"

A little later I revisited the post, and saw that the comment had been removed (along with the rest of the comments in the thread).

But I also discovered that my flag had been marked as "declined".

I don't remember the EXACT text of the comment, but it included the phrase *"you should first learn social skills"*, including a link to Interpersonal Skills (not to a specific question, but directly to the root of the site), which I interpreted as blunt attack.

It surprised me that a flag of "unfriendly" would be declined for something like that.

Beyond the fact that the comment was unnecessary, and that the final result is that this and the other comments have been deleted, my "lesson" here is that by rejecting my flag the moderator indicates *"do not mark this type of comment anymore, this is not considered unfriendly or ungentle"*.

I want to better understand this so my future flags won't get rejected, and could be more useful (if I flag the right comments or posts).

Comment: Probably just a mistake, it happens. A single declined flag isn't going to affect anything. Your flag was correct if the phrasing matches what you presented.

Comment: Here's a stretch - maybe instead of it being unfriendly, it's just "no longer needed"?  It's conversational and not orthogonal to the actual post itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @KevinB. The end result does affect my understanding of what I should flag or not. I hope I wasn't very imprecise in my recollection. Since the comment is gone, I have to rely on my memory. I'm think I got the gist of it right.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't flag it as "no longer needeed" because I thought it was unfriendly. If the phrasing more or less matches what I describe above, wouldn't' you say it's unfriendly?

Comment: I'd lean more towards it being not needed, personally.  Both types of comments are not needed but I'd conjecture someone being unfriendly is someone who intentionally goes out of their way to belittle someone based on their background, creed or circumstance rather than a blanket, not exactly friendly  but not exactly *targeted*, snarky remark.

Comment: ok, I think that just saying "you need to learn social skills" it's unkind on itself. Maybe I'm wrong. That's what I try to figure out.

Comment: Could the comment have been deleted by the commenter, after it was flagged? I can't remember if those flags show as Declined or something else.

Comment: @Makoto: I consider telling someone to learn social skills as rather rude. It's certainly not something I would expect to hear in a normal conversation.

Comment: I've seen that comment in context... It was definitely an insult. Someone (A) tried to convey something to the author of that comment (B), but failed to get the point across, at which point "B" deemed it necessary to insult "A" for their implied lack of social skills...

Comment: @BDL:  It's not that I disagree, but I could see both flags realistically applying here.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think that's the point here. I could have used another type of flag. But my question is "was I right or wrong on marking it as unfriendly".

Comment: i'm pretty sure all flags that are "ended" due to deletion alone are marked "helpful"

Comment: If't like that, @aynber, I would think it a very silly system that send the potentially wrong signal to users flagging comments.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus. Do you remember if my phrasing of the comment above is more or less correct, and mostly represents the comment I flagged? Should I correct something?

Comment: @SteveMarooni you could look in this [comment archive](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/197298) (archives all comments on meta) and see if you can find it I guess.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat. No idea something like that existed. Wow!

Comment: It was on [this MSO question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=423768&user=&room=197298) instead, @Cerbrus

Comment: The only way I could see this not being an accident is if a mod decided NLN was not a severe enough flag and unfriendly/unkind or rude/abusive should've been used instead to have the comment removed more urgently

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry, I fat-fingered that one and realised the mistake after :(

Answer (score 22):

I think that your flagging of the comment was appropriate.  I can't speak to any reason that a diamond moderator would decline the flag, but I don't see any reason why the flag *should* be declined.

In the moment, it's not the sort of comment you'd need to see on any post, regardless of circumstance of tone.  So, it should be removed accordingly.

Don't hesitate to flag these kinds of things in the future; this coming from a mere mortal.  This kind of comment doesn't belong.

Answer (score 14):

That flag should not have been declined.
For one, it is clear that the comment should be removed because it is meta-commentary at best. On top of that, there is no chance that someone would say *"you should first learn social skills"* on good faith, especially when accompanied by a link to the home page of the Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange.

1. The comment alone is generally uncalled for. It is nothing but alienating towards users with real social communication barriers (including dyslexia, neurodivergences, and even English as second/third language people).
2. Even if the site contains advice on how one should communicate with other users, it is utterly unhelpful to refer to the main page of a whole repository without pointing a specific post from which a certain exchange could have been improved.
   In fact, anyone posting a shallow link like that should know better. By that same reasoning, a link to Duck Duck Go, Bing or Google search would have been acceptable. It is not, for [well established](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280426/should-comments-saying-google-it-be-flagged) [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added).

It is not possible to correct the outcome of a comment flag, but don't be discouraged from flagging such comments in the future. Declined comment flags generally do not affect your ability to flag more comments.

Comment: Just for clarity, the comment WAS removed. Only that the "unkind" flag declined. I interpreted (right or wrong) the chain of events as a moderator looking at the comment, deciding all the comments could be deleted, but that my flag should be decliend because I flagged something that wasn't "unfriendly enough".

Comment: I understood that the comment was removed, @SteveMarooni. But the flag outcome leaves the false idea that you should not have flagged it (or flagged it as unfriendly), which I say was wrong. In any case, moderators have made mistakes in the past, and this may have been just another mistake. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402442/should-a-veil-of-anonymity-have-a-say-in-how-we-flag-offensive-comments https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389413/what-is-the-sites-position-on-name-calling-with-a-somewhat-mildly-offensive-wor

Comment: @E_net4 okay but a flag decline leading to a false idea is a mistake in itself. It is good that there are venues like this where that can be outed. People must stop reading too much into mere bookkeeping events.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with your flag - the comment is rude and condescending. It should have been accepted, and the person who posted it should be warned that comments like that aren't allowed. First off, telling someone they have no social skills is rude enough. Secondly, the generic link to the entire Interpersonal Skills side makes this even more condescending; it kind of reminds me of the [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added) LMGTFY links and ["you can Google this in 5 seconds!" type comments](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).